# inject in Authentication guard is giving me type any in angular 17

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular17, angular-guards

I create a functional guard in angular 17

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export const checkoutGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
    const customerService = Inject(CustomerService);
    const router = Inject(Router);
    if(customerService.isAuthenticated()) {
         return true;
    } else {
         return router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
};
```

I get the error  customerService.isAuthenticated is not a function.
I declared the service in app.config.ts  `providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient(), CustomerService,]` 
this what iI declared in routes `{path:'checkout', component:CheckoutComponent, canActivate:[checkoutGuard]}`
this is the service class

```
@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class CustomerService { 
     isAuthenticated():boolean {    return true;   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is to use `inject` instead of `Inject`, please change it

import:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
```

`inject` -> used outside constructor to load dependencies from DI

`Inject` -> used inside constructor to load dependencies from DI (sometimes needed)

---

We can remove `CustomerService` from the `app.config.ts` providers array, since that is reserved for environment providers only, then in the customers service we can set `providedIn: root`, which means the service is accessible throughout the application, so even inside guards!

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomerService {
    ...
```

Then you need to check how you have defined, `isAuthenticated` it should be a function/method, if its a property please change the if condition to

```
export const checkoutGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => { 
    const customerService = inject(CustomerService); 
    const router = inject(Router); 
    if(customerService.isAuthenticated) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return router.navigateByUrl('/login'); 
    } 
};
```

Comment: isAuthenticated is method that return a true i added the code